# How to change Static jtable limit to dynamic (static object array to dynamic)

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, static, jtable

the size of table limit is set as static limit and i want to change that to dynamic

**here jtable & object declared.**

```
    public  JTable issuetable = null;   
    static Object[][] data;
```

**here is my jtable**

```
public  JTable getIssues() {
    issuetable = new JTable();


    String[] colName = {"Member", "Book", "Issue Date", "Return Date ",
            "Remarks" };
    List<Issue>issues=ServiceFactory.getIssueServiceImpl().findAllIssue();
```

**the size of issuedata is limited to 100000 .. i want to change the limit to dynamic..**

```
    data=new Object[issues.size()][100000];

    for(Issue issue:issues){

        data[i][0]=issue.getMemberId().getName();
        data[i][1]=issue.getBookId().getName();
        data[i][2]=issue.getIssueDate();
        data[i][3]=issue.getReturnDate();
        data[i][4]=issue.getRemark();
        data[i][5]=issue;
        i++;
    }
```

if u know answer please share here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21796021/2587435), You were using a `DefaultTableModel`. Keep in mind, a `TableModel` is a data structure in itself. There is no need at to store the data in two data structures, i.e. your `data[][]` *and* the `DefaultTableModel`.  The underlying structure of `DefaultTableModel` is a dynamic `Vector` of `Vector`s.

What you can do is this. Just declare your `DefaultTableModel` with 0 rows, using this constructor

- [`public DefaultTableModel(Object[] columnNames, int rowCount)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html)

Then just add rows dynamically to the structure with

- [`public void addRow(Object[] rowData)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) - Adds a row to the end of the model. The new row will contain null values unless rowData is specified. Notification of the row being added will be generated.

So basically, your declaration will be like this

```
String[] colName = {"Member", "Book", "Issue Date", "Return Date ", "Remarks" };
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(colName, 0);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Then just add rows like

```
String member = "Stack";
String book = "overflow";
Data issueDate = date;
....
Object[] row = { member, book, issueDate, returnDate, remarks };
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
model.addRow(row);
```

---

Please read the [DefaultTableModel api documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) to see more constructors and methods available

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an array, use a dynamically resizable data structure in your implementation of [`AbstractTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data). This [`EnvDataModel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513) is an example that contains a `Map<String, String>`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying all the data from your List to the DefaultTableModel you can use your List as the data structure for a custom TableModel. Then you can add/remove Issue object from this TableModel.

See the `JButtonTableModel.java` example from [Row Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for an simple example of how the `RowTableModel` can be extended to give you this functionality.

Using this approach the data is only ever in one place and you can access Issue objects directly from the TableModel.